# Getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute loc

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror, pandas-loc

```
infections = []

for i in range(0, 20):
    read_nii(raw_data.loc[i,'infection_mask'], infections, 'infections')
```

On executing this code, I am getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'.How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Can you share how `raw_data` is defined/initialized?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that:

1. You have a **string** variable named *raw_data*.
2. From this variable you created a *DataFrame* (named, say, *df*).
3. You attempt to retrieve some data (from *infection_mask* column,
   from first 20 rows).
4. But instead of retrieving these data from *df*, you attempt to
   retrieve them from the variable holding raw data (string).

Other possible scenario is that *raw_data* some time ago was a *DataFrame*,
but due to some error in your code you have overwritten it with some **text**
content.

Before the offending instruction add `print(type(raw_data))`.
Probably the result will be *str* (a string).

Then analyze each case when something is written to *raw_data* variable.